# Can't generate a surface plot in scilab

Tags: plot, compiler-errors, scilab, surface

I'm having trouble generating a three-dimensional surface plot in Scilab.  I keep getting the error:

!--error 999 
Objplot3d: x vector is not monotonous.

I'm using the command:

```
plot3d(x,y,z)
```

where x and y are 200X1 matrices (aka column vectors) and z is a 200X200 matrix.  I thought maybe I had to transpose y, but that led to the same error as well.

Comment: Are your x and y linear?

Answer (score 0):

`help plot3d` requires, indeed, that the first two arguments be monotonous (ie sorted). I wish someone could tell me why!

Since your `x` (and possibly `y`) is not ordered, which causes the error, you just need to sort them, and then pay some attention to keep the `z` values where they belong. Something like:

```
[newx,ix]=gsort(x);
[newy,iy]=gsort(y);
newz = z(ix,iy);
plot3d(newx,newy,newz)
```

(`ix` is the permutation such that `x(ix)==newx`)